# An Elliptic Integral - What's the Simplest Answer?

Tags: integration, special-functions

I have

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\left(R^{2}-\epsilon^{2}\right)\sqrt{R^{2}-\epsilon^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}
$$

which Mathematica thinks is

$$
2R\left(R^{2}-\epsilon^{2}\right)\left(E\left(\frac{\epsilon}{R}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{R^{2}-\epsilon^{2}}{R^{2}}}E\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}-R^{2}}}\right)\right)
$$

where $E(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind, given by

$$
E\left(k\right)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}d\theta\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}
$$

though I think if you do this 'by hand' there is a simpler answer Mathematica can't find due to the many relations between the elliptic integrals. Can anyone have some sort of attempt at finding it?

Comment: Is that first integral stated correctly? As stated presently the first factor is just a constant and so the result is just the second-kind elliptic integral.

Comment: Assume $R > \epsilon > 0$, if you do it by hand, you get $4 R(R^2-\epsilon^2)E\left(\frac{\epsilon}{R}\right)$. Looks like MA doesn't know whether $R > \epsilon$ or not.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, with an aded factor $4$ because the interval of integration is here $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @achillehui Maybe it's a clever answer to take both cases into account. If it's the reasom, it should be possible to add the inequality to `Assumptions` (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)) It may also be asked on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: @achillehui's interpretation is bolstered by the second identity for $E(k)$ at this [page](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE/17/01/), keeping in mind that they use $z=k^2$ as the argument of $E$.

Comment: I think MA derive the expression by simplifying the integral over $[\pi/2,\pi]$ using the identity:
$$\sin(\theta+\pi/2) = \cos\theta \quad\text{ instead of }\quad \sin(\pi - \theta) = \sin\theta.$$ 
i.e.
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \sqrt{R^2 - \epsilon^2\sin^2\theta} d\theta
=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{R^2 - \epsilon^2\sin^2(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4})} d\theta\\
= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{R^2 - \epsilon^2\cos^2\theta}d\theta
= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{(R^2 - \epsilon^2) + \epsilon^2\sin^2\theta}d\theta\\
= \sqrt{R^2 - \epsilon^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1 - \frac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2 - R^2}\sin^2\theta}d\theta
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried first the antiderivative $$\int\left(R^{2}-\epsilon^{2}\right)\sqrt{R^{2}-\epsilon^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}d\theta=\frac{R^2 \left(R^2-\epsilon ^2\right) \sqrt{\frac{2 R^2+\epsilon ^2 \cos (2 \theta
   )-\epsilon ^2}{R^2}} E\left(\theta \left|\frac{\epsilon
   ^2}{R^2}\right.\right)}{\sqrt{2 R^2+\epsilon ^2 \cos (2 \theta )-\epsilon ^2}}$$ So $$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(R^{2}-\epsilon^{2}\right)\sqrt{R^{2}-\epsilon^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}d\theta=4 R (R^2-\epsilon^2 )  E\left(\frac{\epsilon ^2}{R^2}\right)$$

Hoping that this helps.

Comment: There is a typo, you have $E(\frac {\epsilon^2}{R^2})$ but it must be $E(\frac {\epsilon}{R})$.  Do you agree?.

Comment: I think that there are two notations which differ from place to place.

Comment: Thanks! Its important to use my definition of the elliptic integral and not the Mathematica one, so use the convention in the comment above.

Comment: Whether you use $E(k)$ as Maple does, or $E(m)$ as Mathematica does, where $m=k^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Maple I am obtaining directly

$$4\,R \left( {R}^{2}-{\epsilon}^{2} \right) {\it EllipticE} \left( {
\frac {\epsilon}{R}} \right)$$